# Getting a list of all Smart Cards connected

Tags: c#, interop, x509certificate, smartcard

I'm writing a class that signs a XML document using x509 certificates. I'm already able to get my SmartCard certificate and sign it.

However, to do this I must look for the x509 certificate in the Windows Keystore, so I must know something about my SmartCard, like the Issuer Name, or the Serial Number. That's nice.

But I want a more convenient approach to get the SmartCard certificate. I had 2 ideas:

- Get all the certificates from the Keystore and look for those who are "coming from a SmartCard". [But I dont think i'm able to get such information](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).
- Interop with `winscard.dll` and get some information about the SmartCard connected to my computer, so I could use it to find the right certificate, but this isn't working:

  ```
  [DllImport("winscard.dll")]
  public static extern long SCardListCards(
     uint hContext, int pbAtr, 
      int rgguidInterfaces, int cguidInterfaceCount, 
      [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] ref string mszCards,
      ref int pcchCards);

  [DllImport("winscard.dll")]
  public static extern long SCardEstablishContext(uint dwScope, 
      int pvReserved1, 
      int pvReserved2,
      ref uint phContext);
  ```

And here is a test method. The `string crds` holds the list of SmartCards.

```
[TestMethod]
public void TestInterop()
{
    uint handle = 0;
    Interop.SCardEstablishContext(0, 0, 0, ref handle);

    string crds = "";
    int pcch = 0;
    Interop.SCardListCards(handle, 0, 0, 0, ref crds, ref pcch);
    Assert.IsTrue(crds != "");
}
```

This test fails everytime, because `crds` never changes.

If I try to return `crds` as a `byte[]`:

```
    [DllImport("winscard.dll", EntryPoint = "SCardListCards")]
    public static extern long SCardListCardsRetBytes(
       uint hContext, int pbAtr,
        int rgguidInterfaces, int cguidInterfaceCount,
        ref byte[] mszCards,
        ref int pcchCards);
```

My `byte[] crds` becomes:

- `byte[] {171}` when I initialize it with `byte[] crds = {};` why 171?
- `byte[] {0}`   when I initialize it with `byte[] crds = new byte[32];`and why 0?

How can I get the SmartCard certificate to sign a XML message? And if you want to give me a bonus answer, why this Interop I did isn't working?

Comment: `SCardListCards` is returning no SmartCard list because you might be searching them in the wrong domain.
Try searching the SmartCard in the system context, not in user context. 
Eg:  `Interop.SCardEstablishContext(2, 0, 0, ref handle);`

Comment: Tried, and didn't work. I also tried to interop with SCardListReaders,  and that worked. Now I tried to initialize the crds variable like this: `string crds = new string('\0', 1000);` but the results are the same. The string doesn't change.

Comment: It seems that you need to call `SCardListCards` twice: first time to get the buffer length, and second time to actually fill the buffer.
Take a look at this example: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winscard.scardestablishcontext

Comment: Yeah, that works! But the function doesn't do what I expected... My problem isn't resolved yet, but you helped a lot! Thanks.

Comment: Actually I think you DID solve my problem. I think now I can get the SC's serial number, and use it as an identifier!

Comment: @RicardoPieper Can you post the working code as an answer to your question?

Comment: Yes, I will. It turned out I deleted the code because it is feasible using just C#. You need to get a `X509Certificate2`, get its `PrivateKey`, cast to `ICspAsymmetricAlgorithm` and verify if the `ICspAsymmetricAlgorithm.CspKeyContainerInfo.HardwareDevice` is `true`.
[See this link.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.security.cryptography.cspkeycontainerinfo.hardwaredevice(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I discovered a way to know if a `X509Certificate` came from a SmartCard using only C#. That solves the problem for me, and it's been a while since I wrote the code, I deleted the interop C# and C++ code. This works for me:

```
if (certificate.HasPrivateKey)
{
    ICspAsymmetricAlgorithm aa = certificate.PrivateKey as ICspAsymmetricAlgorithm;

    if (aa == null || !aa.CspKeyContainerInfo.HardwareDevice) 
         DoWhateverYouWant(certificate);
}
```

It is not a problem for me if the card is not connected in the moment the code is run. If you want to get a list of SmartCards connected to your PC, it is feasible by using the `winscard` native API.